# hyperledger fabric world state cannot be read by other peer node

Tags: go, hyperledger

I setup a hyperledger fabric environment with the default configure file from [enter link description here](https://github.com/yeasy/docker-compose-files) deploying pbft network, however, with default 0.6 version fabric. I call putState in vp0((I generate the date in query context of vp0 and use channel passed it to invoke context (because we can only call putState in invoke context). as other node do not have this data, it will just ignore putState in other nodes) and when call getState again, only vp0 can read the vale stored by putState while vp1-vp3 cannot get that value, it return empty. any ideas on this issue?

Comment: Welcome to SOF! It's a lot more likely to get a response if you increase readability of your question by applying basic formatting and utilizing the powers of markup.

Comment: This is referring to an unsupported Fabric version, one of the pre-release developer previews. Consider closing this question unless you feel it also applies to a released version.

Comment: The PBFT consensus is not yet available in the released versions of Fabric. Keep an eye out for SBFT consensus in a future release.